# Rails can connect to PostgreSQL with GitHub Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, github-actions, github-ci

I have been battling GitHub actions for a while now. I had to switch to GitHub Action after using Travis for a while and cannot set it up to run tests for Rails application. The problem is that no database is started for Rails to connect to and create the database from migrations.

This is my workflow .yml file:

```
name: Ruby on Rails CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, develop ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ruby-version: ['2.6', '2.7', '3.0']

services:
  postgres:
    env:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres        
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5
    
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up Ruby
  uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
  with:
    ruby-version: 2.7.3
    bundler-cache: true # runs 'bundle install' and caches installed gems automatically

- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    yarn install
    
- name: Build and Test
  run: |
    sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
    bundle exec rake db:migrate
    bundle exec rake test
```

The error I am getting from the Actions tab:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:83:in `rescue in new_client'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.3/x64/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.3/x64/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `new'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78:in `new_client'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/runner/work/Escape-Room-Planner/Escape-Room-Planner/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.3/x64/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.3/x64/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have looked at multiple videos and Stack Overflow discussions regarding this issue, and nothing worked so far. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass correct test db config ENV. Check and set your variables in `database.yml` for test db.

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV.fetch('PG_DATABASE', 'postgres') %> 
  host:     <%= ENV.fetch('PG_HOST',  'localhost') %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch('PG_USER', nil) %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch('PG_PASSWORD', nil) %>
  port:     <%= ENV.fetch('PG_PORT', 5432) %>
```

Or add test db config ENV to your `workflow.yml`:

```
- name: Build and Test
  env:
    PG_DATABASE: postgres
    PG_HOST: localhost
    PG_PORT: 5432
    PG_USER: postgres
    PG_PASSWORD: postgres
    RAILS_ENV: test
  run: |
    sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
    bundle exec rake db:migrate
    bundle exec rake test
```

Check working [example](https://medium.com/@OwenTran/github-workflow-for-rails-ci-34209a53d19e).